# Nexus Remote User Token authorization when deploying

Tags: nexus, sonatype

I have a question regarding Nexus RUT capability. After setting it up, getting http header read, adding this user name to security.xml and mapping the role to this user, I am able to authorize in Sonatype Nexus GUI.

Question is, how can I authorize when trying to deploy artifact to Nexus repository using, lets say, Maven?

`curl -I http://localhost:8080/nexus/service/local/status`

returns

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Thu, 11 Jun 2015 10:41:59 GMT
Server: Nexus/2.11.3-01
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
WWW-Authenticate: BASIC realm="Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager API"
Content-Length: 0
```

but

```
curl -I -H "X-Forwarded-User: admin" http://localhost:8080/nexus/content/
```

returns

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 11 Jun 2015 10:44:35 GMT
Server: Nexus/2.11.3-01
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Last-Modified: Thu, 11 Jun 2015 10:44:35 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Using credentials in maven project and trying to deploy site after [this tutorial](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/_publishing_a_maven_site_to_nexus.html), I am getting error

```
Uploading: .//project-summary.html to https://my.site.com/nexus/content/sites/site/
[WARNING] Required credentials not available for BASIC <any realm>@federation-sts.site.com:443
[WARNING] Preemptive authentication requested but no default credentials available
https://federation-sts.site.com/adfs/ls/?SAMLRequest=fZJdT4Mw........... - Status code: 200
Transfer finished. 5671 bytes copied in 0.404 seconds
 Transfer error: java.io.IOException: Unable to create collection: https://my.site.com/nexus/; status code = 302
```

I would really appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: The ID of the URL in the distributionManagement section of your pom needs to match the ID of a server section in your settings.xml file that has the your login credentials.

Comment: Hi @rseddon, both ID`s match and are the same in pom and server section in settings.xml